# How to define an option with two arguments?

Tags: xkeyval

I am writing a package in which I want to define an option `myvalues` in such a way that

```
\usepackage[myvalues={10,11}]{mypackage}
```

would execute `\mycommand[10]{11}` and

```
\usepackage[myvalues=11]{mypackage}
```

would execute `\mycommand{11}`.

I know how to define an option with just one value using `xkeyval` package

```
\DeclareOptionX{myvalues}{%
  \mycommand{#1}%
  }
```

but I am not sure how to extend it to behave as described above with two arguments.

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example showing your entire usage?

Comment: I’ve been staring at your comment for a while. I think you should apologize.

Comment: About the minimal example: the site is full with XY-questions. Depending on what your commands should do, it’s quite likely that better ways to accomplish your needs can be suggested. To begin with, something like `myvalues=[10]11` might be simpler to implement and to use.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use the xstring package to parse the comma delimited string.

Comment: It seems clear to me what you are asking (two example inputs, and the corresponding outputs). I know that PGF/Tikz have some keys with multiple arguments. `pgfkeys` can be used independently of PGF/Tikz, so you might have some luck with that, but I'm not sure if it natively supports multiple arguments or if it is a Tikz extension that allows you to create such keys.